# How to do sorting in mvc contrib grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

i want to do sorting in the mvc contrib grid....so far i have i used this coding in

homecontroller.cs

```
public ActionResult Sort(GridSortOptions Sort)
    {
        using (ProductsDataContext db = new ProductsDataContext())
        {
            var categories = db.Products.ToList();
            if (Sort.Column != null)
                categories =categories.OrderBy(Sort.Column, Sort.Direction);
            ViewData["sort"] = Sort;
            return View(categories);

        }

    }
```

Here i am getting a error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change this line:

```
var categories = db.Products.ToList();
```

to this:

```
var categories = db.Products;
```

Or change this line

```
categories =categories.OrderBy(Sort.Column, Sort.Direction);
```

to this:

```
categories =categories.OrderBy(Sort.Column, Sort.Direction).ToList();
```